# Storing Multiple Values (Foreign Key References) in One Column Oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, database-normalization

I am trying to design a database for a restaurant.  I have my restaurant items that make up a restaurant order.  One order can contain many items.  Within the order I want to reference multiple items (foreign key).  Below are sample data from the tables.
[image: Items Table with PK ITEM_ID]

[image: Orders Table with FK ITEM_ID]

Is there a way to store multiple ITEM_ID in the Orders table referencing the Items PK ITEM_ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, but - you should normalize data model (so - you shouldn't do what you meant to). "Solution" is to create a new table, e.g. `ORDER_ITEMS`:

```
create table order_items
  (order_id  number constraint fk_oi_order references orders (order_id),
   item_id   number constraint fk_oi_item  references items  (item_id),
   --
   constraint pk_oi primary key (order_id, item_id)
  );
```

It would contain *combination* of order ID and all items it contains.